# Details of the Proof of Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello I want to ask some details concerning the proof of Cauchy-Goursat Theorem. How did it follow that since every z and $z_0$ is in the subregion $C_j$, then $\vert z - z_0 \vert \leq \sqrt[]{2}s_i$ where $s_i$ is the side of the square $C_j$. To be specific in my question, where did the term $\sqrt[]{2}s_i$ came from?

Comment: If two points $z$ and $z_0$ are in a square of side length $s$, then the maximal distance between them is achieved if they lie on the two ends of a diagonal of the square, with maximal distance being $\sqrt{2}s$ from the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The [diameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter#Generalizations) of the unit square is $\sqrt 2$, i.e. this is the biggest distance that occurs within the square. Accordingly, it is $\sqrt 2\cdot s$ for a square of side $s$.